# Paper js 'dot' paths showing up in firefox but not in IE or Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, paperjs

Using the code in the paper js sketch [here](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#S/hZJBa8JAEIX/ypCLESS2PSoeil4LQlt6qD2su2OyJNkJm4laxP/e2dWqrZYGAtmZb96bvGSXOFVjMkqeS2RdJINEkwnn4RBeCoTaOlt3NRjbsnIagUORuhahUC0wgfEqX/iFk4ElrsgjrKy3Lo+kwy0DuacwMBMQcI2OR4FnoioT+dm38gTux+eG2l41wr3qnGZL7iRKG5diH3YRYFli6lExghLvDTSKC1DOQG7XCJal3LKnEkFTRX50mIrUJA7M5THtj8/17MBPAy5Mb1kpXfaugTdrosjD+LTJozHBD/Na3jlEFRKJXpsCPZ64T+pAV1aXaC4WypQxKWYNWceHhfZ/hiDJXoSwVl7cGlkGJWBjKpwHkagBcoX+kpipvolc2ItK/zQWq9a16Dm9GxwV/tnstfm1V8PRs7nl1vCP4HVFLRrB2Xd4bGhyLVWYVZSnATray2+7lM9eRtk2Gb1/7L8A) I am able to see the dots that are drawn by simply clicking without moving the mouse. Also you can see the element is in fact added in all 3 browsers. However, Chrome and IE do not display the element and I cannot for the life of me understand why.

```
// The minimum distance the mouse has to drag
// before firing the next onMouseDrag event:
tool.minDistance = 1;
tool.maxDistance = 1;

function onMouseDown(e) {
    // Create a new path and give it a stroke color:
    path = new Path();
    path.strokeColor = 'black';
    path.strokeWidth = 2;
    // Add a segment to the path where
    // you clicked:
    path.add(e.point);
}

function onMouseDrag(e) {
    var top = e.middlePoint;
    var bottom = e.middlePoint;
    path.add(top);
    path.insert(0, bottom);
}

function onMouseUp(e) {
    var pt = e.point;
    path.add(pt);
    path.closed = true;
    console.log(path);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got a reply from Jürg Lehni

> It's probably a difference of the underlying rendering system, but an
>   open path with only one segment should simply not be rendered,
>   something that we should handle in the library internally.
>
> A closed path should be rendered if it defines handles, as that can
>   actually be a tiny little loop.

I had to setup specific behavior to handle dot paths. In my case I used circles.

Answer (score 1):

This is how i solved it:

```
    function onMouseUp(e) {
        var pt = e.point;
        if (path.segments.length < 2) {
           // draw a dot
           pt.y ++;
        }

        path.add(pt);
        path.closed = true;
        console.log(path);
    }
```